# Adding year value from datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem in date time picker on vb.net 10. what I want is year is added by specific number, and the value of date and month still the previous from the date time picker.
example :
`datetimepicker1.value is 2/28/1993`

the result is
`datetimepicker2.value is 2/28/2043`

I already try with
`datetimepicker1.value.year + 50
datetimepicker1.value.month
datetimepicker1.value.day`
but I don't know how to convert it to date time type, because in my region date format DD/MM/YYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
datetimepicker1.value.addyears(50)
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help. be sure to accept an answer that helped you solve your issue so this question will show up as answered.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing really to do with the DateTimePicker.  You get a Date from the Value property and then what you do with that is up to you.  If you want to use the Month and Day components of that Date then go ahead.

```
Dim newDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddYears(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddYears(50)
```

or

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddYears(50)
```

[DateTimePicker.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Add this if you need format like `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, especially for the date format

Comment: @RezaKahfi.You are most welcom.. Glad i coud help ..mark this answer as useful If i helped you

Comment: @RezaKahfi ok no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddYears(50)
```

## [DateTimePicker1.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)